# Async/Await SemaphoreSlim only newest task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I use a trackbar as control for input-values for a morphological image operation. this operation takes a while so I want to use async/await to keep the moving of the trackbar scrolling smooth.

what I did:

```
private static SemaphoreSlim Sema = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1);
private async void Operation()
{
    if(pictureBox_Image.Image != null)
    {
        await Sema.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() => DoStuff());
        }
        catch{}
        finally
        {
            Sema.Release();
        }
    }
 }
```

But this way it still calculates the result for all trackbar values.

How can I remove all waiting tasks, so after the calculation for one value is done, only the newest task/trackbar-value will be used for the next calculation?

Excample:

Trackbar Values     [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
calculation starts witch 0 -> finishes and shows result -> trackbar-value is now 4 -> doesn't calculate with 1,2,3 -> only with 4.

Comment: *insert standard "async void is bad" comment here*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So also supply a CancellationToken to your method, and act accordingly when it is cancelled. It's not clear how this is being invoked, so generally, need to keep hold of the most recent CancellationTokenSource that provided a token at the calling site. It should be cancelled before the next call to Operation.

```
private static SemaphoreSlim Sema = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1);
private async void Operation(CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    if(pictureBox_Image.Image != null)
    {
        await Sema.WaitAsync(ct); //throws if cancelled... will not proceed
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() => DoStuff(ct)); //DoStuff should be checking this CT too
        }
        catch{}
        finally
        {
            Sema.Release();
        }
    }
 }
```

...to be used in your event handler:

```
currentCancellationTokenSource.Cancel(); //class property/field
currentCancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
currentCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
Operation(currentCancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

This might cause an OperationCanceledException somewhere that you will need to handle.